# Is there a cycle-free graph with a Hamiltonian circuit?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I have an question about graphs. Is there any graph in which there is no cycle, but it has a Hamiltonian circuit? I think there isn't such a graph.

Am I right?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph without any cycles can't contain a Hamiltonian circuit since a Hamiltonian circuit is a cycle.

If you meant Hamiltonian *path* instead of Hamiltonian *circuit*, then there is a solution. A Hamiltonian path is itself an example of a graph that trivially contains a Hamiltonian path but does not contain a cycle.

If you were to add any edge to a Hamiltonian path, you would immediately introduce a cycle and the resulting graph wouldn't satisfy your requirements anymore. So, the only type of graph that contains a Hamiltonian path but no cycles is a [simple path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: how can i do that?